# How do I connect to an Ethereum testrpc Blockchain from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I have installed testrpc and able to run the demo example (MetaCoin) of trufffle. I want to know if there is a way to use truffle/testrpc in a Ruby on Rails application. Can somebody please help me with these questions.

> How to connect to [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) blockchain running locally on a windows machine from a Rails application?

And

> How to use the [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) library in rails?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like this https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how do I connect to [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to interact with the testrpc blockchain using Rails app. Like how do I use it from controller and views?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use any Ethereum node with ruby you can use [ethereum.rb](https://github.com/marekkirejczyk/ethereum.rb).

Keep in mind that testrpc is a test node, so it only makes sense to use it when writing tests.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Rails but for REST based calls Blockapps have REST APIs to interact with Ethereum Blockchain (Strato)...maybe you can try this

Answer (score 0):

I have published [Ethereum on Rails](https://github.com/q9f/ethereum-on-rails) on Github. It is a demo/template application that allows authenticating Users in your Rails application with an Ethereum wallet (e.g., MetaMask).

[image: Screenshot of the Demo]

You can use this repository as a template to create your custom Rails application that already has Ethereum support bundled. It uses `ruby-eth` gem for Ethereum account management.